# Keeping track of multiple index in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there any way to keep multiple index in ng-repeat?

Eg. if having a list of fruits as such:

```
$scope.fruits = [
  {type: 'apple'},
  {type: 'orange'},
  {type: 'apple'},
  {type: 'banana'},
  {type: 'banana'}
];
```

In my template I have a ng-repeat going through the fruits.

```
<ul ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
 <li>{{fruit.type}}</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to keep an index for each fruit type such that I can add that index to the line in the template to get the following result

```
* apple - number 1
* orange - number 1
* apple - number 2
* banana - number 1
* banana - number 2
```

I can't see how $index will help me, as it looks at the overall list (right?). I have tried adding a tracking variable in the controller, but this triggers an infinite loop because of how $digest works and it keeps triggering a change.

Answer (score 0):

It is option to do this. 
use ng-repeat directive:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in fruits"
```

and you can use it in html:

```
<li>{{key}}- {{value}}</li>
```

Remember about not having spaces in this expression since is regexp processed, so 
 `(key, value )` wouldn't work, but `(key, value)` would.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your solution, however, would give the result "<li>type- apple</li><li>type- orange</li>..." which is not the result I'm after.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't correct in my comment. The result of this solution will be "<li>0 - {"type":"apple"}</li><li>1 - {"type":"orange"}</li>..." were the use of key will be the same as using $index. It is still, however, not what I'm looking for